# NS objects don't have recognized members

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

New to both Swift and Xcode, so apologies for what might be a very obvious question.

I'm writing a simple NSStatusItem app and have run into something that seems like it should have an obvious solution. Working through various tutorials, I'm setting the icon for the menu to an image that I'm trying to size appropriately and set as a template.

```
var icon = NSImage(named: "klick_sensei_icon")
icon.size = NSSize(width: 16, height: 16)
icon.setTemplate(true)
```

I'm getting build errors on the second and third lines:

> AppDelegate.swift:36:9: 'NSImage?' does not have a member named 'size'
>
> AppDelegate.swift:37:9: 'NSImage?' does not have a member named 'setTemplate'

Checking the documentation for NSImage shows that it does have both.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `icon` variable is `optional` due to `NSImage(named...` possibly not returning an image due to missing image file or mistyped name, etc.

So to access the members you need to unwrap `icon` like

`icon!.size = NSSize(width: 16, height: 16)
icon!.setTemplate(true)`

...although you should test that `icon` is not nil before you unwrap it. e.g.

```
if let icn = icon {
    icn.size = NSSize(width: 16, height: 16)
    icn.setTemplate(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NSImage(named:) returns an optional NSImage and you need to unwrap it, try this

```
var icon = NSImage(named: "klick_sensei_icon")
icon?.size = NSSize(width: 16, height: 16)
icon?.setTemplate(true)
```